# How to set resourceDirs in gradle IDEA module?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a separate resource folder which I want to add to IDEA classpath. The reason I don't use main/resources is I need to have the folder outside of JAR to allow XML config files edition.

This is what works in IDEA

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        resourceDirs += file('src/dist/etc')
   }
}
```

When I press "reimport from Gradle" the folder is mapped as Resource Folder.
So IDEA understands resourceDirs property.

But Gradle 2.2 fails:

```
Could not find property 'resourceDirs' on org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule_Decorated@329c1075.
```

How can I set a resource dir in IDEA from Gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer myself:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        ext.set('resourceDirs', [])
        resourceDirs += file('src/dist/etc')
   }
}
```

However, due to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133399 it still won't work despite the fact that IDEA now marks 'src/dist/etc' as resource dir.

Comment: I doubt this is going to work. No `resourceDirs` property exists or has ever existed (where did you get this from?). You can introduce one via `ext.`, but none of the existing plugins are going to be aware of it. Perhaps try `sourceDirs += [file('src/dist/etc')]`.

Comment: IDEA recognizes it http://git.jetbrains.org/?p=idea/community.git;a=blob_plain;f=plugins/gradle/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/gradle/model/internal/init.gradle;hb=68bfa5e533660c6de9ec3dbfa8c7e2938d6a6b1a

However, due to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133399 it doesn't really copy resource files.

I can't use sourceDirs because files end up in JAR and I need them in an external folder.

Comment: You mean the Jar created by IntelliJ?

Comment: End package looks like "bin, etc, lib"

Scripts from bin run project JAR from lib and set classpath to etc. 
So I don't want resources to go to both etc and JAR. (Jar created by Gradle)

Comment: Reconfiguring `idea.module.sourceDirs` won't affect Jars created by Gradle. Anyway, instead of `ext.set(...)` try to change the second line to `resourceDirs += [file('src/dist/etc')]` (can't omit the `[]` in Groovy 2.x, which is what's used by Gradle 2.x).

Comment: The problem is, idea.module.sourceDirs does not work as well. I created IDEA-133399.

Comment: and can't omit ext.set because Gradle then fails with "Could not find property 'resourceDirs' on org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule_Decorated@57991440.
"

Comment: Sounds like an IntelliJ issue then. In any case, it's safer to use `[]` with Gradle 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

```
idea.module.resourceDirs += file('src/dist/etc')
```

Should work since Gradle 4.7 where support for specifying idea resourceDirs has been added.

Comment: It's a duplicate of the answer.

Comment: syntax is the same, correct, but it has been implemented only recently as an out of the box feature in Gradle 4.7.

Answer (score 0):

A bit complicated example:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    if ( ! project.name.equals("core")) {
        idea.module.resourceDirs += new File(
               project(":core").projectDir, "src/main/resources")
    }
}
```

Works with Idea 2018.3 & Gradle 4.10.

Even current Idea has limitation: it doesn't support extension of classpath by resources from dependent subprojects... It is not enough to declare:

```
dependencies {
    project(":core")
}
```